# Sqlite query to retrieve all the records that have changed due to a certain column

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, subquery, unix-timestamp

I would like to retrieve all records from my table where a status change has happened in one of the columns in my table. Please look into the following table :

```
   BANFN    BSART   FRGKZ           ERNAM   ERDAT
   11111111 NB      2                A      1533247200
   11111111 NB      4                A      1534111200
   22222222 NB      2                C      1548111600
   22222222 NB      4                C      1559858400
   33333333 NB      2                D      1559858400
   33333333 NB      4                D      1559858400
   44444444 NB      2                E      1559858400
```

My question now is

1. I want to retrieve all the BANFN basis wherever there was a change in the column FRGKZ from 2 to 4
2. Then another column where I want to see the lag between these two events from the ERDAT field which is in a Unix timestamp format

Sor For example for the first `BANFN 11111111` the output should look like the following :

```
    BANFN    ERNAM BSART   LAG_In_Between                           Final_Status_FRGKZ
    11111111   A      NB   ERDAT at status 4 - ERDAT at status 2     4
```

The output should have the following columns :

`BANFN ERNAM BSART LAG_In_Between Final_Status_FRGKZ`

Comment: Are there other values of `FRGKZ`?  Can there be rows in-between?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: there is only one more value '1' but that is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a convenient place to use `lag()`:

```
select t.*, (erdate - prev_erdat)
from (select t.*,
             lag(frgkz) over (partition by banfn order by erdat) as prev_frgkz,
             lag(frgkz) over (partition by banfn order by erdat) as prev_erdat
      from t
      where frgkz in (2, 4)
     ) t
where frgkz = 4 and prev_frgkz = 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0f41eaa859b17de0f34bdc325cad9329) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that the filtering is quite important.  The subquery filters to just "2"s and "4"s, so the previous is always a "2" or a "4".

The outer query only returns the "4"s where the previous is a "2".

Comment: I am getting a syntax error but to me, the query looks fine. Only in the first select statement, I can have an alias created for (erdat - prev_dat) as lag_date or something. but I am not sure why this is throwing a syntactical error. The SQLite DB studio that I am using says that it did not recocgnise the function Lag.

Comment: @Django0602 . . . Are you using an older version of SQLite that doesn't support `lag()`?

Comment: I dont think so... I do have the latest version of SQLite DB studio .. 3.2.1 is there any other updated version which I am missing?

Comment: That is actually relatively old, if that is the version of SQLite.  Window functions were introduced in 3.25.

Comment: Got it. Update to the latest one and ran the query. The query gave me 0 results.. which ideally should not be the case

Comment: @Django0602 . . . It works in SQL Fiddle.  I added a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` twice: once to get the difference with the previous `erdat` for the same `banfn`, once to get the previous `fgrkz`. The outer query filters on records that have `fgrkz` set to `2` and whose previous `fgrkz` is `4`.

```
select
    banfn, 
    ernam, 
    bsart, 
    lag_in_between,
    fgrkz final_status_frgkz
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        erdat - lag(erdat) over(partition by banfn order by erdat) lag_in_between
        lag(fgrkz) over(partition by banfn order by erdat) lag_fgrkz
    from mytable t
) t
where fgrkz = 4 and lag_fgrkz = 2
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error but the query looks fine to me. Would you mind checking this again? also in the first select statement, I only need the Final_Status_FRGKZ which gives me the final value from FRGKZ field. The SQLite DB studio that I am using says that it did not recocgnise the function Lag.